# flutter google maps nearby search api type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, google-maps, google-places-api, flutter-getx

I'm using the Google New Nearby Search API to generate a list of markers of places around me and I'm getting this error

> type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I'm new at flutter but I managed to get a response back i think the error is happening when convertnig from json after calling the api

this is the json body i get

> ```
> {
>     "places": [
>         {
>             "id": "ChIJH1SlB1OgHBURC9Io_36xG2Y",
>             "formattedAddress": "XV9F+7MW, Amman, Jordan",
>             "location": {
>                 "latitude": 31.968225099999998,
>                 "longitude": 35.874212299999996
>             },
>             "displayName": {
>                 "text": "Sido AlKurdi Mosque",
>                 "languageCode": "en"
>             },
>             "photos": [
>                 {
>                    
>                     
>                 },
>                 
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "ChIJtXIJhK2hHBURntIqDaJGrNg",
>             "formattedAddress": "Al Imam Muslim 22, Amman, Jordan",
>             "location": {
>                 "latitude": 31.9706942,
>                 "longitude": 35.882999399999996
>             },
>             "displayName": {
>                 "text": "مسجد بر الوالدين (ضاحية الحسين)",
>                 "languageCode": "ar"
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

I have converted it to JSON using the dart2json plugin

this is my repo

```
abstract class HttpRepository {
  Future<Response?> googleNearbySearch({
    required Map<String, dynamic> payload,
  });
}}
```

and this is the implementation of the repo

```
    class HttpRepositoryImpl extends GetConnect implements HttpRepository {
      @override
      Future<Response?> googleNearbySearch({
        required Map<String, dynamic> payload,
      }) async {
        var response = await post(
          ApiUrls.googleNearbySearch,
          headers: googleMapsHeaders,
          payload,
        );
        if (response.isOk) {
         
          return response;
        } else if (response.unauthorized) {
          CustomToast.unAuthorized();
        } else if (response.hasError) {
       
          CustomToast.backEndError(message: "something went wrong");
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

this is my controller I'm using getx and get_connect to handle my API calls the code is not complete since I removed some snippets of it

because it is too long  if anyone wants to help me and finds the code lacking I can provide it later

```
 class NearbyMosquesController extends GetxController {
  final HttpRepository httpRepository;
  final CacheUtils cacheUtils;

  NearbyMosquesController(
      {required this.httpRepository, required this.cacheUtils});

  List<NewNearbyMosques> mapModelList = <NewNearbyMosques>[].obs;

  var markers = RxSet<Marker>();

  var isDoneLoading = false.obs;

 Rx<NewNearbyMosques?> nearbyMosquesModel = Rx<NewNearbyMosques?>(null);

 String apiKey = "********************";

 googleNearbySearch() async {
    try {
      isDoneLoading(true);
      final payload = json.encode({
        "includedTypes": ["mosque"],
        "maxResultCount": 10,
        "locationRestriction": {
          "circle": {
            "center": {"latitude": 37.7937, "longitude": 32.3965},
            "radius": 10000.0
          }
        }
      });
      late Rx<Response?> googleNearbySearchResponse = Rx<Response?>(null);

      Position position = await determinePosition();
      googleNearbySearchResponse.value =
          await httpRepository.googleNearbySearch(
        
        payload: json.decode(payload),
      );
      var result = jsonDecode(googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body);
    
      // Set<Marker> newMarkers = createMarkers();
      if (googleNearbySearchResponse.value == null) {
        return null;
      }
      mapModelList.addAll(RxList<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(result)
          .map((e) => NewNearbyMosques.fromJson(e))
          .toList());
      nearbyMosquesModel.value = NewNearbyMosques.fromJson(
        googleNearbySearchResponse.value!.body,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      createMarkersFromList();
      debugPrint(
          'this is another error in the catch   ${e.toString()}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n');
      CustomToast.backEndError(
        message: 'error while calling google',
      );
    } finally {
      isDoneLoading(false);
      createMarkersFromList();
      CustomToast.backEndError(
        message: 'in the finally',
      );
    }
  }

  createMarkersFromList() {
    mapModelList.forEach((element) {
      var places = element.places;
      
      if (places != null) {
       
         for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
       

        markers.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(
              places[i].id.toString(),
            ),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
              BitmapDescriptor.hueAzure,
            ),
            position: LatLng(
              places[i].location!.latitude!,
              places[i].location!.longitude!,
            ),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: places[i].displayName.toString(),
              snippet: places[i].formattedAddress.toString(),
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        );
         }
      }
    });
  }

 @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    try {
    
      getCurrentLocation();
      await googleNearbySearch();
     
      await determinePosition();

      super.onInit();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Initialization error: $e');
    }
  }}
```

this is the curl for the post call
curl -X POST -d '{ "includedTypes": ["restaurant"], "maxResultCount": 10, "locationRestriction": { "circle": { "center": { "latitude": 37.7937, "longitude": -122.3965}, "radius": 500.0 } } }' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY" \ -H "X-Goog-FieldMask: places.displayName" \ places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchNearby

here I think im getting the response and converting it to a list of map<string, dynamic> to use it as a marker I'm not sure though as I said I'm still new

Answer (score 0):

There is an Issue With your Return type.

If u have Used [http: ^1.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Then U need to use

> 

```
class HttpRepositoryImpl extends GetConnect implements HttpRepository {
  @override
  Future<Response?> googleNearbySearch({
    required Map<String, dynamic> payload,
  }) async {
    var response = await post(
      ApiUrls.googleNearbySearch,
      headers: googleMapsHeaders,
      payload,
    );
    if (response.isOk) {
     
      return jsonDecode(response);          <-----------  jsonDecode
    } else if (response.unauthorized) {
      CustomToast.unAuthorized();
    } else if (response.hasError) {
   
      CustomToast.backEndError(message: "something went wrong");
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```